# Convert PBI Desktop dataset to push dataset

Tags: powershell, powerbi, dataset, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I have a report and dataset created in Power BI Desktop and published to Power BI Online. I need to update the rows of this dataset from an API and try to use a REST API, but I can only update a push dataset and look for a method to convert my normal dataset. Would it be possible to convert or copy the existing structure to facilitate the creation of this Push Dataset?

I tried converting using a Windows PowerShell module PowerBIPS, but that module has had an error since last year and apparently doesn't work anymore.

Comment: You can't change dataset's mode (i.e. from AsOnPrem to Push). This can be set only when the dataset is created. However, the actual problem is that you are trying to use Power BI as a database, which it is not. Just store your data somewhere where you can easily update it (a database is a good choice) and let Power BI refresh the dataset when necessary.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov, I had to choose this option, I'm updating the database by sending the spreadsheets to SharePoint using the Graph API. My point is that it would be very simple to be able to get data like in PBI Desktop or just use the same dataset. Anyway, thanks for the tip.